# How can i fix "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I use core data and mvvm in my project and one of the properties uses the Integer data type, how do I implement it in a textfield, when I use a textfield an error like this appears.

[image: error appears "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int?>' to expected argument type 'Binding'"]

how to make the text field not error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using TextField's `init(_:value:format:prompt:)` initialiser rather than the `init(_:text:)` that you are using. Maybe something like...

```
TextField("Jumlah Barang", value: $addItem.jumlah, format: .number)
```